# Helpers - asp.net MVC core (dotnet core 1.1)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, .net-core

**Hi everyone, I'm going to start with a new experience with dotnet core using  the MVC pattern.**

> Which are the new helpers for checkbox, textarea and other?

In this moment the relative page is empty : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/html-helpers

I've tried this :

`<input asp-for="myField" class="form-control" type="checkbox" value="False"/>`   but doesn't work!

Thanks in advance.

> ```
> <div class="form-group">
>       <label asp-for="myField" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
>       <div class="col-md-10">
>           @*<input asp-for="myField" class="form-control" type="checkbox" value="False"/>*@
>           <span asp-validation-for="myField" class="text-danger"></span>
>       </div>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Please post whole html here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want use [HTML Helpers](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/787320/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-HTML-Helpers-and) you can still do the same like in .Net Framework but MS want to change a bit [HTML Helpers to Tag Helpers](https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/asp-net-core-1-0-goodbye-html-helpers-and-hello-taghelpers/). [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) are new feature with .Net Core

Answer (score 1):

First check if you got reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers package in your project.json

Secondly remember about `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` at the beginning of your view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I get this when trying to Install-Package : Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers 6.0.0-rc1-final is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers 6.0.0-rc1-final supports:
  - dotnet5.4 (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.4)
  - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)

it seems doesn't work with .net core

Answer (score 0):

I've been got  error in the browser, because the field which I set is Nullable.

I've did the migration, update the database and now work!